# Too many re-renders and code not refreshing

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

so I am getting the error too many re-renders when trying to update the state of an array.

I declare an array called sampleFriends, made up of objects with fields "name", "location", and "picture" (each element of the array looks similar to: {name: 'John', location: 'Boston', picture: TestImage}).

Then I use useState as follows:

```
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')
  const [friendMatches, setFriendMatches] = useState(sampleFriends)
```

I also have a TextInput component:

```
<TextInput
      value={searchQuery}
      onChangeText={setSearchQuery}
      onChange={search()}
      placeholder="Search Contacts"
      keyboardType="default"
    />
```

And a search() function that looks like this:

```
  const search = () => {
    const coincidences = sampleFriends.filter(({ name }) => name.includes(searchQuery))
    setFriendMatches(coincidences)
  }
```

I want to render the users whose name matches searchQuery, and coincidences gives me the users, but I can't use setFriendMatches to update the matchesState (which is what I'd like to render). Hope it makes sense and thanks for your help!!

UPDATE:
Some responses told me to change onChange={search()} to onChange={search} and that eliminated the error. However, now search never runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Line 4 in `TextInput` from `onChange={search()}` to `onChange={search}`.

By calling the function you are triggering an infinite re-render at each re-render.

There are probably other issues since it's unlikely that your component wants a double onChange event listener, I made a simple demo to show you how to possibly manage these scenarios in a cleaner way: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eijegp

Comment: Thanks!! Now I don't get the infinite re-render. However, search never gets called (I tried console.log a few things and they never appear)

Comment: I added a demo to show how to manage it better, sometimes it's faster than trying to explain by words.

Comment: That is so helpful thank you very much!! However, I am using react-native, and <TextInput> is a component that I import from react-native and which has onChange and onChangeText (which behave differently https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange) so it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

In the onChange event, just mention the function name like this `onChange={search}` or if you need to put some parameters, call it within a function as below.

This is what your final code block should look like.

```js
<TextInput
      value={searchQuery}
      onChangeText={setSearchQuery}
      onChange={() => search()}
      placeholder="Search Contacts"
      keyboardType="default"
    />
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: If he writes ` onChangeText={setSearchQuery(some_value_needed_here)}` he's gonna have the same infinite re-render issue. onChangeText probably will automatically pass the value to setSearchQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this:

```
  <TextInput
  value={searchQuery}
  onChangeText={setSearchQuery}
  onChange={search}    // <-  This One is Important
  placeholder="Search Contacts"
  keyboardType="default"
 />
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now I don't get the infinite re-render. However, search never gets called (I tried console.log a few things and they never appear)